# I have created database and initial log file size set to 15mb , i am shrinking the log file by using dbcc shrinkfile(khadar_LOG,5); GO

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

QRY

```
    USE HEMA

    ALTER DATABASE HEMA

    SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;

    GO

    DBCC SHRINKFILE(HEMA_LOG,5);

    GO

    ALTER DATABASE HEMA

    SET RECOVERY FULL

    GO
```

after executing this query i have checked space by using dbcc sqlperf(logspace) 
i found log space used(%) is keep on increasing

Please help what does it mean if log space used is keep on increasing ..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your databases are NOT set to auto-shrink.Databases that are shrank at continuous intervals can encounter real performance problems or You can change the database to the Simple recovery model. see here: http://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/how-to-clear-transaction-with-dbcc-shrinkfile/

Answer (score 0):

It is in FULL recovery mode so have a look at what is causing the log space not to be reused. Run the following:

```
USE db_name;
go
dbcc loginfo
```

Look at the status column. My guess is that it is status 2. This means that those portions of the log are awaiting a transaction log backup before the log space can be re-used.
You should set up transaction log backups to meet your recovery requirements. Anywhere from every 5 minutes to every x hours. The more often you run the log backups, the smaller the
log files will need to be sized. The size is dependent on the amount of insert/delete/update activity that goes on between each log backup.
The bottom line is that if you run backups of the transaction log you shouldn't be swapping to SIMPLE and shrinking.